# XSL-FO - how to add a information page in the last with out header & footer for this page?

Tags: xsl-fo

In XSL-FO how to add a information page in the last, we don't need header & footer for this page?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a page at the end of the output, regardless of previous pagination, you can use a new `fo:page-sequence` referencing a specific `fo:simple-page-master` for the last page.

Example:

```
    ...
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page-last">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block/>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

If you just want to change the layout of the last page, you can use `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` and use `page-position="last"` for the condition.

Example:

```
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="my-page-sequence">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="my-page-last" page-position="last"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="my-page"/>
    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```